# How to test if a DelayedJob is calling a method from another class?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, tdd

I'm setting up specs to test whether or not a job calls a method under certain conditions.

This is what I have so far:

```
describe RandomJob do
  context "when payload[:type] = MyModel" do
    let!(:my_model) { create :my_model }
    let!(:payload)  { { type: "MyModel", id: my_model.id } }

    context "when Model exists" do
      it "calls MyModel.fire! with payload" do
        RandomJob.perform_now(payload)
        expect_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:fire!).with(payload)
      end
    end

    context "when Model does not exist" do
      it "does not call MyModel.fire!" do
        RandomJob.perform_now(payload)
        expect_any_instance_of(MyModel).not_to receive(:fire!)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Just to be sure my way of testing worked. I setup my job like this:

```
class RandomJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(payload)
    @payload = payload

    fire_model!
  end

  private

  def fire_model!
    my_model&.fire! @payload
  end

  def my_model
    MyModel.find(@payload[:id])
  end
end
```

I expected the first test to pass, and the second to fail. However, my first test is failing while the second is passing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seeing the full errors messages from the first test case would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the expectation *before* the `perform_now` call.

```
    context "when Model exists" do
      it "calls MyModel.fire! with payload" do
        expect_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:fire!).with(payload)
        RandomJob.perform_now(payload)
      end
    end

    context "when Model does not exist" do
      it "does not call MyModel.fire!" do
        expect_any_instance_of(MyModel).not_to receive(:fire!)
        RandomJob.perform_now(payload)
      end
    end
```